# How to capture user selections with dialog

Tags: linux, bash, shell, dialog

I am updating a shell script which uses [dialog](http://linux.die.net/man/1/dialog) create a text-based UI.

When I create a radiolist or checklist, I can't figure out how to make a selection in the displayed dialog.

For example, taking an example from [here](http://unstableme.blogspot.com/2009/12/linux-dialog-utility-short-tutorial.html):

```
#!/bin/sh
dialog --backtitle "OS info" --radiolist "Select OS:" 10 40 3 \
        1 "Linux" off \
        2 "Solaris" on \
        3 "HPUX" off \
2> result.txt
echo "User selection: " `cat result.txt`
```

In the resulting dialog, I can use cursor keys (or number keys 1-3) to **change** the highlighted item in the list. But I can't figure out how to actually **select** the item (set the X in its control).

When I highlight an item and press ENTER, the output is always "2".

**UPDATE**

I find I can make a selection by clicking an item with the mouse. I was expecting it to work with keyboard-only input.

I'd still be interested to know if there is a way to make a selection using the keyboard - I guess there must be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use <kbd>space</kbd> to select the highlighted item.

Comment: That's it, thank you! I guess I should have been searching for standard keyboard accessibility. I was searching specifically for dialog and turning up nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the 2 solaris option is kept selected.
UNIX dialog raidolist uses <kbd>spacebar</kbd> key event to change the selection.
Unless <kbd>spacebar</kbd> is used, we can change the selection, else default selection will be resulted.